# Can I run multiple instances of plank with separate settings?

Tags: plank

Let's say I want to have plank run on the side of the screen as well as the bottom *at the same time*, as can be done with some other docks - is this possible?

If yes, how?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes this is possible

Most of the elementary project has settings hard coded to a `gsettings` XMl file. Gsettings is a gnome daemon to handle settings and manage them.

Luckily, plank uses a separate file for storing preferences.

1. First change the settings of the plank which is currently running with `plank --preferences`. Change the position to the left or the right, because otherwise both planks will overlap.
2. Then create the new dock with `plank -n one --preferences`. The `one` is just a name - you can choose a different one if you wish.
3. Open system settings, go to applications then open the startup tab. Click on the + icon below and add the command `plank -n one`.
4. Then log out and back in, and you have set up two docks.

Comment: Will that technique work for other distros as well? I am using Arch and love Plank, so I don't want to screw anything up. Many thanks!

Comment: i didn't test it on arch. but i think it will.  the only thing you have to find out by yourself is how to add a command to the start up of the system. like my step 3 in the explain above.

as long as the command is the same it should work.

Comment: It should be noted that though recent versions of plank lack a schema, Plank still uses gsettings. You can edit the settings for plank using `dconf-tool` or `gsettings`.

Answer (score 0):

yes this is possible
and for a full discription check this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xNIWq4hgw78&t=14s